# C# How to make a foreach loop not override a string variable

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, row

I'm trying to pass a PHP project to ASP.NET and I'm doing some testing. Returning to doubt, I have this code done:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace project_t
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string level_text;

        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) => people_box_repeater_method();

        public void people_box_repeater_method()
        {
            using (MySqlConnection mysql_connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter mysql_data_adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM employees", mysql_connection);
                DataTable data_table = new DataTable();
                mysql_data_adapter.Fill(data_table);

                DataView data_view = new DataView(data_table);
                data_view.Sort = "name";
                data_view.Sort = "function";
                data_view.Sort = "sector";
                data_view.Sort = "location";
                data_view.Sort = "mail";
                data_view.Sort = "phone";
                data_view.Sort = "photo";
                people_box_repeater.DataSource = data_view;
                people_box_repeater.DataBind();

                string vartest = "4";
                foreach (DataRow data_row in data_table.Rows) {
                    if ((string)data_row["level"] == vartest) { level_text = (string)data_row["level"]; System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data_row["level"]); }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is in this part:

```
string vartest = "4";
foreach (DataRow data_row in data_table.Rows) {
    if ((string)data_row["level"] == vartest) { level_text = (string)data_row["level"]; System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data_row["level"]); }
}
```

I put two data outputs, one on the .aspx page where my html code is `<% = level_text%>` and another one on the output console.

In my database, I have four rows that have the value "4" in the "level" column.
[At the console output, it returns me four rows corresponding to the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyO1T.png)

[Now in the .aspx page the number "4" appears once.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVgSF.png) I want to appear four times the number "4" like in the console output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with 7 consecutive call to sort for the same DataView?

Comment: perform your `DataTable` manipluations *before* creating `DataView` and assigning that `DataView` as `DataSource`. In other words, move your 3 "problematic" lines up, after ` mysql_data_adapter.Fill(data_table);`

Comment: It is correct as is. You are replacing the value of the variable with the value "4" so at the end you have "4" in that variable. If you want to concatenate the outputs you use label_text += value.

Comment: You'll get the last value in `level_text ` as you are using the same variable. try using a List and hold all the matched data and run a foreach loop in the client side to show all at a time.

Comment: @Steve The 7 consecutive calls to sort have been fixed and the `+= value` worked, thanks!

Comment: @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter I'll try to create a list. Maybe it will work best for my future purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your if statement is true you do this.
 level_text = (string)data_row["level"];
This means it gets set every time to the same value.
If use += instead of = it will add something to the string.

For example your code is now doing level_text = 4; Every time, with += you will get level_text=4444